# Подсчет элементов массива

Tags: delphi

Имеется массив А(N,M). Как подсчитать количество положительных и отрицательных элементов массива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i:=0 to n
 for j:=0 to m
  begin
   if a[i,j]=>0 then pol=pol+1
   else otr=otr+1;
  end;
```

Comment: Из курса алгебры:  

А > 0, число А называется положительным
А < 0, число А называется отрицательным
А >= 0, число А называется неотрицательным